# MySql query extract value with between syntax

Tags: mysql

These are my rows in MySql database table:

```
+------------+----------+-------------+
| theDate    | theHour  | theUserCode |
+------------+----------+-------------+
| 2015-11-16 | 06:30:00 | XX2111905   |
| 2015-11-16 | 21:30:37 | XX2112111   |
| 2015-11-16 | 22:21:29 | XX2112111   |
| 2015-11-16 | 17:15:18 | XX2142122   |
| 2015-11-16 | 04:22:13 | XX2146905   |
| 2015-11-16 | 15:15:00 | XX2146905   |
| 2015-11-16 | 21:26:00 | XX2148516   |
+------------+----------+-------------+
7 rows in set
```

I need extract from this table the rows with `theHour` between `15:00:00` and `03:00:00`.

I have tried this Sql query but in output I have the `Empty set`.

```
SELECT
    theDate,
    theHour,
    theUserCode
FROM
    `tblUserRegistered`
WHERE
    theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND '2015-11-16'
AND theHour BETWEEN '15:00:00'
AND '03:00:00'
ORDER BY
theUserCode,
theDate,
theHour ASC;
```

Please help me, thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Do you want 3pm to 3am, or 3am to 3pm?

Comment: I am not sure why you are using the between with `theDate`. You can simply do `theDate =  '2015-11-16'`?

Comment: @Rahul I think he wants a certain portion of the day, over several days.

Comment: Wouldn't this be simpler if date and time were stored as a single entity?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen:- Yes, may be the case, but at present it makes no sense. Also I agree with Strwaberry that it would be much easier if the two entities are combined as single one.

Comment: Your query works for me. What is the data type of your theHour field?

Comment: Agreed.  He should just use one timestamp instead of having 2 columns.  I hope no one downvotes his question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `HOUR()` function in my query below to handle the check by hour.  This query will include records *later* than 3pm (15 hours), or *earlier* than 3am (03 hours).

```
SELECT theDate, theHour, theUserCode
FROM tblUserRegistered
WHERE theDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB('2015-11-16', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND '2015-11-16'
    AND (HOUR(theHour) >= 15 OR HOUR(theHour) <= 3)
ORDER BY theUserCode, theDate, theHour ASC
```